Git run automatically run a script against multiple commits/branches/tags
I'm doing lots of experiments with different machine learning models. Generally this looks like running a small (~200 line) script, waiting about 2 minutes, recording some metrics about the output, making a small change (use a different function, try a different value, etc) and repeat.
I've done automatic hyperparameter tuning before, and that's not what I'm looking for here. I want to test a relatively small (~20) number of different changes, but these changes generally are tightly coupled. So I can't just change a function, I have to change a function and try a different value (because the function requires certain values)
It's easy for me to make the change piecemeal, but it would be a pain to specify it for the computer.
Can I make each of the changes I want, store them as different branches, and use git to run a testing script on a set of different branches/commits? I know there's something similar with git bisect, but I don't think I can easily (ab)use bisect for this purpose.

Yes, or you could write a patch generator and serially reset and apply the patches, or if you're not using all of your cores or ram you could do it in parallel. You for the unique content, tools for formatting. Use your tools. Git's just one of them. If you expect 20 variations is at the high end of what you'll ever need the tools might not be worth investing in, but if you're expecting to be doing little production runs like this, best get good with the whole toolkit.

You can use Michael Haggerty's excellent git test program for this. It is typically used to run build/lint/unit test commands against every single commit on a branch while working on a feature, but there is nothing that prevents you from creating many test branches and run tests against commits on those.
Similarly to bisect git test does iteratively check out each commit it is testing, so for that reason the most pleasant usage experience is to create a separate worktree to run the tests in.
